# call multiple Sql files in a single SQL file in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How do call multiple sql files in a single sql file, in postgres

For example I have aaa.sql, bbb.sql, ccc.sql.

I want to execute this 3 files from xxx.sql.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 16):

If you are running these files through `psql` you want the `\i` directive ("execute commands from file").

***xxx.sql:***

```
\i aaa.sql
\i bbb.sql
\i ccc.sql
```

If you are passing these through some other program you will need to combine the files yourself - I do not believe there is any SQL-standard way of executing external files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I will test and confirm if I was able to achieve it or not

Comment: Doesn't look like working yet
Not sure if I am missing something.
do I need semi colon at the end??? -Not Really !!!

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working" - I assure you this *does* work -- Refer to [the psql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-psql.html)

Comment: It worked. Finally :-)
Thanku
Problem was -- it was not able to recognize the file and O specifiled the relative path for the file and its working 
Thank you once again

Comment: @Trip Trip, don't forget to give voretaq credit for his answer!

Comment: The [current version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) also supports the `\ir` or `\include_relative` meta-command. When invoked from a script, `\ir` interprets file names relative to the directory in which the script is located, rather than the current working directory.

Answer (score 5):

On a bash shell you can do it also with a simple `find -exec`

```
find sql/ -name *.sql -exec psql -U user -f {} \;
```

Comment: Requires that you use `"*.sql"` rather than `*.sql`

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but will serve your purpose: 1) Put all of your script files in a folder; and 2) use a bash script to iterate through your files and run psql. For example:

```
SCRIPTS_DIR=/home/myproject/scripts
DATABASE_NAME=database_name

for file in $SCRIPTS_DIR/*.sql
    do sudo -u postgres psql $DATABASE_NAME -f $file
done
```

This is in fact a little better because you won't have to type your files' names.